# Are all moderators listed in the Users->moderators page?

Tags: support, moderators, user-list

I've just noticed something: [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) is indicated as a moderator (diamond icon on right + explicitly written on the user page), but does not appear on the [moderator list](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

Is this a bug, or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: He's not a moderator; he's a developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a bug, or do I misunderstand something?

Actually you misunderstand something. Moderator list doesn't include <s>developers</s> employees of SE. And Marc Gravell is a [developer of SE](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007/).

Comment: You might want to mention community managers..

Comment: Ah ok, now it makes sense. But then I would suggest the user profile should mention something like *SE developper ♦* instead of *Moderator ♦*

Comment: @Seth - Yeah just updated.

Comment: @Boris - Mostly you can find this information from their **About** page.

Comment: So as a side question, *in addition* of being employees, are they also technically moderators of SO? (e.g., if I flag a post, do they receive the notification and have moderator privileges?) If yes, then it still makes sense to keep the *Moderator ♦* mention on their about page, otherwise I think it is at least misleading, at most incorrect. (not a big deal, though)

Comment: @Boris - devs and Community Managers has more privileges than Moderators. And yes they can and do moderate.